# Controlling browser caching with ASP.NET and IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, caching, pagespeed

[Google PageSpeed](http://pagespeed.googlelabs.com) suggests the following this for my website as a high priority.

> The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime.
>   Specify an expiry of at least one week in the future for the following
>   resources:

And suggests [further reading](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html#LeverageBrowserCaching).

I am using Windows Server 2008 r2, .net framework 4.0, asp.net and IIS 7.5. How can I increase the cache expiry for some files?

I've tried the following web.config, but it doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <sessionState mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
          <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="10.00:00:00" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure this is not working. I just knocked up a simple page with a single image as a  test. Added your config section exactly and checked in firebug.

Here are the headers.

[image]

Looks ok to me.

Comment: I should add, I checked in yslow before the change and it recommended expiry on the image also. After the change it passed yslow.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that. But there seems to be nothing wrong with the config. Maybe it wasn't applied to the correct site/instance. Maybe the IIS is configured incorrectly. Not sure..

Comment: no it is correctly made. I can't pass google. I want to pass google because i think it affects also SEO.

Comment: Also  i am not getting responce headers like you have very interesting. THis is what i get for responce headers   HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Mon, 11 Jul 2011 18:13:26 GMT
Etag: "28124e83c71fcc1:0"
Cache-Control: public;max-age,max-age=864000

Comment: It is also interested that it does not show all the images at google test. Some images passes test even though all of them is coming from same source with same way.

Comment: Yslow also still telling me that i am failing : http://img84.imageshack.us/img84/5720/stillfail.png

Comment: Do you have a separate site instance for static.monstermmorpg.com? Did you update the correct web.config for the correct instance?